# Simple question on group theory

Tags: physics, symmetry, bifurcation

Suppose we have the following system of differential equations:

\begin{cases}
\frac{dx_{i}}{dt}=f_{i}\left(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\right), & i=1,\ldots M\\
\\
\frac{dy_{j}}{dt}=g_{j}\left(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\right), & j=1,\ldots N
\end{cases}

where $\boldsymbol{x}=\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{M}\right)$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=\left(y_{1},\ldots,y_{N}\right)$. We also suppose that the $M$ equations in $x_{i}$ are symmetric under exchange of the index $i$, while the $N$ equations in $y_{j}$ are symmetric under exchange of the index $j$. Moreover, we suppose that in general there is no symmetry if we exchange a particle $i$ with a particle $j$. In other words, these differential equations describe a system with two categories of particles (e.g. neutrons and protons), and within each category the particles are identical or indistinguishable.

My questions are:

- what is the symmetry group of the whole system?
- if for some reason a particle in one category starts to behave
  differently from all the other particles in that category (through a branching point bifurcation), can we
  talk about spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Many thanks in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: By no stretch of the imagination is this a group theory question. This is physics.

Comment: I do not agree. This is equivariant bifurcation theory, which is deeply related to groups. Please have a look at this link http://www.scholarpedia.org/articl/Equivariant_bifurcation_theory And this is a general question, I talked about particles as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know anything about equivariant bifurcation theory, but I can say a couple of things about this system.

As the problem is stated, the symmetry group is $S_M \times S_N$ (permutation groups of $M$ and $N$ objects) where the first factor acts on the $x$-space and the second on the $y$ one.

The spontaneous symettry breaking mechanism is when you have a symmetry in your equations, but not in your solutions, so a bifurcation point, as you described, breaks - let's say $S_N$ to $S_{N-1}$ - but it is not a spontaneous symmetry breaking, just a symmetry breaking.